# What is the point of using $_SERVER['document_root']?

Tags: php, server

What is the advantage? If I know the file structure of the project like the back of my hand, why can't I just use relative urls? For instance, if we want a file in the folder `trial` and the file is called `test.php`, what's the advantage in doing

```
require $_SERVER['document_root'] . "/trial/test.php";
```

when we can do

```
require "test.php"; //assuming we are in the trial folder
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if you have to hand it off to someone (just as a for instance)? They may not know it like the back of their hand. Personally, I use a config file that has the a bunch defines in it for common folders I use, all based on the root of the site (where I put my config file) so when I include I would do `ROOT_DIR.'/folder/file.php'` or if it's a common function folder, it would be like `FUNCTIONS.'/myfunction.php'` all based on root (my config file location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is incredibly useful especially when working in your development environment. If you're working on large projects you'll likely be including a large number of files into your pages. For example:

```
<?php 
//Defines constants to use for "include" URLS - helps keep our paths clean 

        define("REGISTRY_CLASSES",  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/SOAP/classes/"); 
        define("REGISTRY_CONTROLS", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/SOAP/controls/"); 

        define("STRING_BUILDER",     REGISTRY_CLASSES. "stringbuilder.php"); 
        define("SESSION_MANAGER",     REGISTRY_CLASSES. "sessionmanager.php"); 
        define("STANDARD_CONTROLS",    REGISTRY_CONTROLS."standardcontrols.php"); 
?>
```

In development environments, you're rarely working with your root folder, especially if you're running PHP locally on your box and using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a great way to maintain URL conformity. This will save you hours of work preparing your application for deployment from your box to a production server (not to mention save you the headache of include path failures).

However it is a personal choice, many frameworks use `dirname(__FILE__)` to work out the application path based on a known file, usually the `index.php`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Suhail, but in a development environment, won't the files always be running from the root folder, so on linux, like the /www/ folder? Therefore, won't the relative urls always hold up no matter what environment you change to? Thanks

Comment: @LostProgrammer Since that's a server variable, you may or may not see it , depending on which web server you're running under (especially IIS). One way to deal with this problem is to set the variable.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "C:/some/absolute/path";
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);`

Comment: @LostProgrammer Relative URLs are cool but what happens when the root changes? Would you want to manually change each set of instruction? Won't that increase the probability of breaking the code?

Comment: yes you are correct, thank - you very much for your insight